# What features would a future, advanced telescope have?

Tags: internal-consistency, technological-development, astronomy

What could it do that we can't do now? What special technological upgrades could it have- making it more advanced than the telescopes we have today. Also, what would we call it?

Comment: Well, considering that modern telescopes are basically the same thing that Galileo had in the 1600s, just bigger and which are sometimes mounted on the pointy end of a rocket...

Comment: Prob making it perceive at a speed faster than light. Probably not feasible but definitely useful.

Comment: It depends on what you call a telescope. If you mean a device which uses optics to form an image of distant objects then the only feasible progress (without some unexpected massive breakthrough in exotic materials) is to make them bigger so that they can resolve smaller, fainter or more distant objects. For example, the Hubble space telescope has a 2.5 meters mirror; the future James Webb space telescope will have a 6.5 meters mirror, which will enable it to gather about 5 times more light; it will also be tuned to longer wavelength light than Hubble.

Answer (score 3):

The three main ways a telescope could be improved are by improving its resolution, increasing its field of view, and reducing noise and errors.  I'm going to assume that you're talking primarily about optical telescopes here, and not radio or other kinds of telescopes.

A telescope's resolution is basically how small of an object it can see.  If two objects are too close together, like a planet orbiting a star, then the objects will blur together, as shown below.
[image]

Now, the resolution of a telescope depends on two things: its diameter and the wavelength it's using.  Assuming we're only looking in the optical, this means that we need to increase our diameter in order to get a better resolution.  Currently, our telescope diameters are limited by how large a mirror we can build.  Almost all research telescopes are reflecting telescopes.  Large mirrors are difficult to make because increasing the size can cause strain and warping of the mirror.  Larger telescopes are also more difficult to steer because they are heavier.  Advanced production facilities and stronger materials could enable us to use larger and larger telescopes, increasing our resolution and letting us see smaller and smaller objects.

The second way to improve an optical telescope is to increase the detector's efficiency.  Current research telescopes use special electronics called CCD's: [Charged-Coupled Devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device).  These are special chips that detect incoming light and convert it to a digital electronic signal, which creates the image.  Right now, our production capabilities limit how big we can build these detectors.  Having larger CCD's would enable us to increase our field of view, allowing us to see more objects in the same image.  Improved detector efficiency would also mean that we could image fainter objects and have fewer visual defects.

Finally, our telescopes are limited by what scientists call "noise".  Noise is essentially stray signals that mess up our image.  These could be photons from a bright nearby source, like a light in the observatory, or errors caused by turbulence in the atmosphere.  Some of these things we are able to get around.  For instance, using space-based telescopes means we don't have to worry about atmospheric turbulence.  Other sources of noise include electronic noise, which is unavoidable, but can be reduced by cooling our detectors and making better chips.

In summary, the two best ways to improve an optical telescope are to make it bigger and to get better electronics.

Comment: CCDs are already near the limit on efficiency: many of them have quantum efficiencies approaching 90% in the optical.

Also, the "larger CCD" problem is usually solved these days by making arrays of smaller CCDs. The Large Synoptic Survey Telescope is planned to have 189 CCDs, each 4k by 4k.
https://www.lsst.org/about/camera/features

Comment: Yes, but mosaicking has its own issues, especially at the boundaries of the CCDs. CCDs are very well-developed, but that doesn't mean that they can't be improved upon.

Comment: Re mosaicking: that's what dithering is for. (And note that if you make your individual CCDs bigger, you increase the readout time, unless you switch to something like CMOS technology).